# Why does 32-bit application use less RAM than 64-bit version, even though 32-bit executable is larger

Tags: .net-4.0

I have created an application in .NET. When I compile a 64bit version and a 32bit version of the same software, the 64bit executable is smaller.

However, when you run them both, the 64bit version uses more RAM.

I'm sure something is happening "under the hood", and was just interested why? (It's not a worry either way)

Thanks.

EDIT: C#.NET 4.0 if it matters.

Comment: I don't get this question. Your title says 32-bit *uses* more memory, the question says 64-bit *uses* more memory. Obviously both cannot be true.

Comment: Your question title and question content seem to conflict with each other.

Comment: I went out on a limb and updated the wording of the title

Comment: My apologies - the title/question is now correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 32 bit applications, pointers are 32 bits i.e. 4 bytes, whereas they are 64 bits i.e. 8 bytes in 64 bit applications. So pointers (e.g. object reference) take up twice as much memory.

Also, in 32-bit applications objects have an overhead of 12 bytes per object, whereas in 64 applications they have an overhead of 24 bytes. Double again.

These affects will be noticed at runtime, not in the dll size.

Comment: So is it worth upgrading to a 64bit with 8gb RAM from 32bit 4gb RAM? I just noticed that I did not have as much RAM available as I may have thought, because now everything consumes double the RAM. So what is the point?

Comment: @gemmo: Not everything consumes double RAM, [just things like pointer addresses](https://superuser.com/a/469480/45163) and object overhead. I would guess that in most applications, these account for less than 10% of the RAM usage.

Answer (score 4):

Pointers are twice as big in 64bit mode. That could explain some (sometimes much) of the RAM usage difference.